# How to convert specific sub-position of byte array to char array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte array, and i need to copy a snippet of the byte array to a char array.

Example:

I have:

`byte[] b = {4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0};`

I want to copy to char array the position 2->5, to char array be like:

`char[] c = {2, 1, 5, 0}`

I tried this method but the final char array is a empty array.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
      byte[] b = {4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0};
      char[] c = byte2CharArray(b, 2, 4);
      System.out.println ("Char array: " + Arrays.toString(c));
    }

    public static char[] byte2CharArray(byte[] array, int index, int size){
        char[] ret = new char[size];
        /* Verify if exist Character size bytes to get from index */
        if(array.length >= (index + Character.BYTES)) {
            for (int i = 0; index < size; i++, index++) {
                ret[i] = (char)array[index];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `ret[i] = ret[i] = ...`? Also, what is the point of casting a `byte` to a `char`?

Comment: sub-array from 2 to 5 has size of 4, however you've passed 3

Comment: @Andreas, OP uses `index < size` condition, so @eparvan comment is correct.  Also it is not clear how OP was going to get `[2, 1, 5, 0]` starting from index 0.

Comment: `index < size`? That's wrong. E.g. if you wanted to copy 3 bytes starting at offset 7, then `7 < 3` is immediately false and nothing would get copied.

Comment: Why would this: `array.length >= (index + Character.BYTES)` need to evaluate to `true` for anything? The length of the array is irrelevant to `Character.BYTES` for your scenario.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `ret[i] = (char)(array[index] + '0')` ? or `ret[i] = Character.forDigit(array[index], 10)` ?

Comment: @g00se Thank you, `ret[i] = (char)(array[index] + '0')` solved the problem. Can you explain why put `'0'` in the end of each char?

Comment: I'll expand on that in an official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since changing `byte[]` elements to `char[]` elements makes little sense if those elements are to be treated *both* as numeric types, I assume you wish to have `char` representations of digits:

```
ret[i] = (char)(array[index] + '0');
```

Would be a quick and dirty way, but prefer the more precise

```
ret[i] = Character.forDigit(array[index], 10);
```

since it's wrong (in theory) to be assumptive about character codes.
Both versions of course do the same thing but the former works by incrementing from the *character code* of the digit zero to form the character code of the digit required. The character code of zero in most encodings is 0x30 and the subsequent digits increment that.